# So, how do I try other people's Django sample code? Case in point: django-allauth

Tags: django

Sorry that this is very much a beginner's question, but yes, I'm only just beginning to learn Django and now want to learn how to implement a user registration.

For that, it appears that [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) does what I'm looking for. I've managed to install it and its dependencies, but fail to setup the included example app.

So how to get the "example" app running? Is there a brief guide on how to install and try other people's Django samples? Googling around wasn't helpful, but I may be looking for the wrong keywords.

I'm grateful for some pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular instance, the example "app" is actually a full Django project. Just change to the example directory and run `python manage.py runserver` from there.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that helped me find the right track. Your command was not enough (and that's where I tripped so far). Reason was that I installed allauth using the `python setup.py install` as described in Python's modules doc (http://docs.python.org/install/index.html). Using your command would then run the example app from the local system's module directory (/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ in my case) instead of the other copy in my home directory.

`python manage.py runserver --settings=settings` was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Example code that comes with a Django app is usually not meant to be directly runnable; you must read it and make the changes to your project in order to integrate the app.